# How to render array of objects inside an object react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

this is my JSON:

```
{
"products": [
           {
               "_id": "5fc9027dd3b8f63398ae8132",
               "name": "Oriz 500g",
               "quantity": 1
           }
       ],
       "status": "CANCELLED",
       "total": 0,
}
```

And I need to render name and quantity from products. I`m rendering like this but it doesn't work

```
<Text style={styles.listProduct}>{data.products.name}</Text>
```

Note: data it comes from

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const response = await axiosApiInstance.get(
      `/orders/get-order-details/5fce356c0fbc3605bffe2060`
    );
    setData(response.data);
```

Comment: If products has one element you can get the element at index 0:  <Text style={styles.listProduct}>{data.products[0].name}</Text>

Comment: but i will have more products, whats the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop in the array and extract the required array item, follow this

```
<View>
    {data.length > 0 && data.products.map((element, index) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.listProduct}>Name: {element.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.listProduct}>Quantity: {element.quantity}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    })}
  </View>
```

modify as your requirement

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.products.map')

Comment: can you console your data in state

Comment: they are coming well, just in the map its not working

Comment: The same error is appearing i dont know why is not getting data

Comment: I have found the solution ```const products = data.products.map((item, i) => (  <Text style={styles.listProduct}>{item.name}</Text>)): ``` and then just calling it {products}

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the answer
`const [data, setData] = useState({ products: [] });`

````const products = data.products.map((item, i) => (  {item.name}));```

and in the return you just call it like this
`{products}`